# Using Applescript UI scripting to set date field in info of TV episode

Tags: applescript, itunes

So that they appear correctly (and usefully!) sorted when viewed from an AppleTV (2nd gen), I'm trying to programmatically set the 'Release Date' of all the TV episodes in my iTunes library. Unfortunately, that field is r/o on the track object, so I'm resorting to setting it via UI scripting.
I've gone through the discovery process of finding the UI element names, but I just can't quite get the desired element to accept input. It has the focus, but key presses don't seem to reach it.

```
tell application "iTunes"
    tell frontmost to activate
    if selection is not {} then

        set originalSelection to selection

        repeat with theEpisode in originalSelection
            set addedDate to (date added of theEpisode)
            if (release date of theEpisode) is missing value then
                tell application "System Events"
                    tell process "iTunes"
                        tell menu bar 1
                            tell menu bar item "Edit"
                                tell menu "Edit"
                                    click menu item "Get Info"
                                end tell
                            end tell
                        end tell
                        delay 1
                        tell window "TV Show Info"
                            activate
                            tell scroll area 1
                                tell group 1
                                    set focused of UI element 2 to true
                                    tell window "TV Show Info" to activate
                                    keystroke "1"
                                end tell
                            end tell
                        end tell
                    end tell
                end tell
                -- I'd prefer to just do this, but the property is r/o
                -- set release date of theEpisode to (date added of theEpisode)
            end if
        end repeat
    end if    
end tell
```

There's a few redundant, ineffective, desperate attempts in there to get the date field to truly take the focus. While it does get highlighted as being the active element, it still doesn't take keypresses. What am I missing?

(This is on iTunes 12.4.1.6, if that makes any difference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But, it's possible on **iTunes 12.4.1.6**, probably they have forgotten to change it in the dictionary.

```
tell application "iTunes"
    repeat with theEpisode in (get selection)
        if (release date of theEpisode) is missing value then
            set addedDate to (date added of theEpisode)
            set release date of theEpisode to addedDate
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: At first I was a little annoyed by that response - that was my starting point. *But* crucially, I'd only ever run it from Script Editor, which honours the r/o aspect that it reports in the dictionary. Running the compiled script from iTunes's scripts menu on the other hand works exactly as I was hoping, so thanks for making me revisit my original solution! One other quirk of Applescript (or a gap in my understanding!) is that getting and setting the dates has to go via an intermediate variable, otherwise a cryptic error is reported.